# Remote-debug a VueJS webpack project

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, remote-debugging, vue-cli

I'm using Visual Studio Code and attempting to configure the [Debugger for Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) extension to work with my webpack project created via [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli).

I am able to attach to the correct instance of Chrome and see logged info in the Debug Console. But I am not able to add breakpoints in the scripts of my `.vue` files.

When I click a line to add a breakpoint dot, sometimes the breakpoints are added on a line somewhere higher up in the file. And sometimes I get this error:

> Error processing "setBreakpoints": Breakpoint at specified location already exists.

Does anyone know why I would be seeing this issue with the breakpoints? Is there anything wrong with my `launch.json` file?

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Set up a webpack project:

   ```
   $ vue init webpack my-project
   ```
2. Open project in VS Code and configure `launch.json` file like so:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Attach",
               "type": "chrome",
               "request": "attach",
               "port": 9222,
               "url": "http://localhost:8080/*",
               "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Start webpack project in development mode:

   ```
   $ npm run dev
   ```
4. Launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled on port `9222` and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/`:

   ```
   $ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-debug
   ```
5. Run the debugger by hitting `f5` and add a breakpoint anywhere

#### Screenshot of webpack source in the dev tools:

[image: screenshot of webpack source in dev tools]

Comment: do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one of my debug configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "trace": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",       // Example: "webpack:///./~/querystring/index.js" -> "/Users/me/project/node_modules/querystring/index.js"
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",                    // Example: "webpack:///src/App.js" -> "C:/project/src/App.js"
        "webpack:///*":     "${webRoot}/src/components/*"                               // Example: "webpack:///C:/project/hello.vue" -> "C:/project/src/hello.vue"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my debug configuration for another low version vue project:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "监听一个已经启动调试模式的Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "trace": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",       // Example: "webpack:///./~/querystring/index.js" -> "/Users/me/project/node_modules/querystring/index.js"
                "webpack:///node_modules/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",                    // Example: "webpack:///node_modules/vux/src/components/toast/index.vue" -> "/Users/me/project/node_modules/vux/src/components/toast/index.vue"
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",                    // Example: "webpack:///src/App.js" -> "C:/project/src/App.js"
                "webpack:///*":     "*"                               // Example: "webpack:///C:/project/app.ts" -> "C:/project/app.ts"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but neither of your configurations have worked for me. I get this message: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)". I've added my webpack source to my post. Also, instead of posting two answers, you should just edit your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#sourcemaps . you need adjust your sourceMapPathOverrides.

The default configure may not fit you case. After adjust, run .scripts command in debug console to view output.

Make sure two points, 1) the .vue or .js file is mapped to correct absolute path
 2) if there're multiple .vue files, let the correct .vue file map to correct path and let others map to wrong path.